# rejectValue message parameters

Tags: spring, grails

How can I pass message parameters to an error message when using `rejectValue`?

This doesn't seem to work (`'default.null.message'` expects a parameter):

```
bookInstance.errors.rejectValue('title', 'default.null.message', ['title'] , 'Title cannot be null')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really how `rejectValue` works.  I think you want to use the `reject` method instead.  See docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html).